# only proceed when function is called

Tags: python, tkinter

The user should pick a matter from the list in the dropdown menu. Then it would give back a schematic drawing of that matter with the Turtle mudole, i do not include that here. I would want it to wait computing

```
m = n - 1
```

after the user's input is registered.

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = ['methaan','ethaan','propaan','butaan']


master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    variable.get()
    if variable == 'methaan':
        n = 1
    elif variable == 'ethaan':
        n = 2
    elif variable == 'propaan':
        n = 3
    elif variable == 'butaan':
        n = 4


button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

m = n - 1
print(m)
mainloop()
```

It gives back that *n* is not defined.

Desired outcome

```
# 0 to 3 depending on what matter you choose.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `n` is local to the function `ok`

Comment: This is a chicken-and-egg situation: you are using `n` before the main loop starts, but you `n` won't be known before the button is clicked.

Comment: I recommend you try printing out the value of `variable` immediately before the first `if` statement. You'll see that it's not what you're assuming it is and that none of your `if` statements will evaluate as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the last 2 lines within the function itself, because they won't get executed if they are under `mainloop`.

Here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = ['methaan','ethaan','propaan','butaan']


master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    if variable.get() == 'methaan':
        n = 1
    elif variable.get()  == 'ethaan':
        n = 2
    elif variable.get()  == 'propaan':
        n = 3
    elif variable.get()  == 'butaan':
        n = 4
    m = n - 1
    print(m)

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything

Comment: I have placed all my code under *def ok():* however there has to be a better way i think?

Comment: You can put the *code* in another function, then call this function inside `ok()`.